# Inline Editing of XHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I'm looking for a tool that allows a non-tech person the ability to edit hard coded content in XHTML. For instance, Pagelime merged with jEditable.

The site is currently static, and I'd basically like to allow one person to log in, click on elements, change the content (P, H1-6, etc), then click enter and write that content directly to that file.

Anyone know of something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

probably one of the easiest options is [Cushy CMS](http://cushycms.com).  you let Cushy access your site via FTP, and it just edits the files when the user changes the content.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks, but Cushy is basically the same thing as Pagelime. Perhaps I wasn't as clear as I could have been - I'm looking for the qualities of Cushy with the on-site editing abilities of jEditable. I want someone to be able to go to *their own* website, log in, and edit directly on their URL, then saving to that same file. Far fetched?

Answer (score 0):

This tool will always use a client side technology like javascript.
So you have an answer in your question...
If you're looking for a CMS including this kind of feature, you can look at this article :
http://www.cmswire.com/cms/micro-cms/zimplit-cms-adds-on-simple-inline-editing-003716.php
You have a demo here :
http://www.zimplit.org/addon_demo.html

Comment: I don't expect it not to use client side technology.